# canonical bundle of a curve on a surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a nonsingular curve of genus $g$ on a surface $X$, then we know by Harthsorne, Chapter-$2$, Proposition $8.20$ that $K_C \cong K_X \otimes \mathcal O_X(C) \otimes \mathcal O_C$, then can this same expression be rewritten as $K_C \cong K_X|_C \otimes \mathcal O_C(C)$?

I guess that tensoring with $\mathcal O_C$ is same as pulling back by $i: C \hookrightarrow X$. Then can we think the above as $K_C \cong K_X \otimes \mathcal O_X(C) \otimes \mathcal O_C \cong (K_X \otimes \mathcal O_X(C))|_C \cong i^*(K_X \otimes \mathcal O_X(C)) \cong i^*(K_X) \otimes i^*(\mathcal O_X(C)) \cong K_X|_C \otimes \mathcal O_C(C)$.

Please correct me if this is incorrect. Any insight is appreciated

Comment: Yes, sure, but this looks like you're getting ready to potentially misuse this - what's pushing you to ask this question?

Comment: @KReiser, I am habituated with $K_C \cong K_X \otimes \mathcal O_X(C) \otimes \mathcal O_C$ from Harthshorne. Sometimes back I saw somewhere this expression  $K_X|_C \otimes \mathcal O_C(C)$. I was trying to understand that whether these two expressions in the right hand side are the same things or not by basic pull back argument. Do you somehow mean that these two expressions are equal but the argument given for sameness is incorrect?

Comment: No, no, no, the argument is fine - it boils down to pullback commuting with tensor product, which is a thing that's very well known to be true. I've just seen students ask a question like this and then say something like "but since $\mathcal{O}_C(C)$ is just $\mathcal{O}_C$..." which is an unfortunate claim to make. So I wanted to check in on your motivation and guard against something like that.